# android - GC_CONCURRENT freed

Tags: android, input, garbage-collection, buffer

I'm developing an android app that gets it's data through the rum-time from a server, a regular socket is opened and the requests are sent to the server and the server responses are received through a regular `InputStreamReader` :

```
 Reader input = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
 String server_response = null;
 char responseLine ;
 while (something) {
            responseLine = (char)input.read();
            server_response = server_response + responseLine;
            // some work 
   }
   return server_response;
```

I sent **4** server requests, I'm receiving the first two corresponding responses and don't receive the other two, instead of that i receive some single chars as a responses and then tons of these GarbageCollector lines:

```
02-17 10:26:08.599: DEBUG/dalvikvm(595): GC_CONCURRENT freed 98K, 77% free 477K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
02-17 10:26:09.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(605): GC_CONCURRENT freed 154K, 4% free 7178K/7431K, paused 18ms+8ms
02-17 10:26:10.238: DEBUG/dalvikvm(605): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 84K, 3% free 7361K/7559K, paused 64ms
```

*(worth to mention that the server responses are really large).*

due to that i tried to change my way of receiving responses to that:

```
input = new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(
                      socket.getInputStream(), 65000));
```

but that gives me the same result. what can i do to overcome that?

**p.s. 1) i can't use `BufferedReader` as the server doesn't send me the responses as lines.**

**2) when i bypassed the first two responses it received the third one normally.**